# Pickle suddenly won't pickle cv2.VideoCapture object

Tags: python, opencv, pickle, video-capture

as part of my work I need to pickle a VideoCapture object (from opencv), and it was no problem until suddenly it started giving me this error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle cv2.VideoCapture objects
```

That is with the following code:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture('some_video.mp4')
pickle_out = gzip.open("file_name", "wb")
pickle.dump(video, pickle_out, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
pickle_out.close()
print("closed")
```

This doesn't happen on any computer, but it does on my main one. The code didn't change, so I assume it has something to do with some settings. Can anyone please help?

(This is with python 3.6)